# Make list of formulas 3 columns

Tags: math-mode, align, multicol

I've changed my earlier question to a more clearer question.

I'm searching for a more easier way to list different formulas in 2 or 3 columns next to each other to create an overview of all the formulas I have to know.

I've used tabular, but that doesn't work with the formulas in mathmode. After that I thought to use the `multicols`-environment but then, the formulas were not good aligned. Some are to the top, middle or bottom aligned but not all the same way.

Do someone have a solution to make these lists in 3 or 2 columns easier?

Comment: Why are you using `multicols` here?

Comment: I use multicols to get the formulas next to each other. Maybe there is a better method?

Comment: Formulas in `tabular` do work

Comment: Only with using `$...$`. But I want to use `$$...$$` because the font-size of the formula is bigger and there is space under each formula

Comment: @iJonathan: **No, you don't want to use $$...$$** -- that's outdated! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what should I use in stead of `$...$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math in tabular works, in p-columns you can use `\[..\]`. Beside this you can always force display style with the `\displaystyle` command.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
\[\sum_x =1 \] & \[\sum_y =1 \] & \[\sum_z =1 \]
\end{tabularx}



\[
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}lll}
\sum_x =1  & \sum_y =1  & \sum_z =1 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a mixed approach, using `glossaries` to store the formulas, but this is not really necessary.

The core feature is the `Q` columntype, using a `p` cell in conjunction with `\[` and `\]`, i.e. th LaTeX replacement of `$$...$$`

This way, the formulas are not aligned at the `=` sign.

```
\documentclass[headings=small,12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{glossaries}


\newglossaryentry{Einstein}{%
  name={\ensuremath{E = mc^2}},
  description={}
}

\newglossaryentry{Pythagoras}{%
  name={ \ensuremath{c^2 = a^2 + b^2 }},
  description={}
}

\newglossaryentry{TrigPythagoras}{%
  name={ \ensuremath{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \equiv 1 }},
  description={}
}



\makeglossaries

\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\[}p{5cm}<{\]}}

\begin{document}

{%
\centering

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{Q}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{List of formulas} \tabularnewline
\toprule[1.5pt]
\gls{Einstein} & \gls{Pythagoras} & \gls{TrigPythagoras} \tabularnewline
\left(x^2\right)' = 2x \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

[image]